Как вставить переменную в кавычки VUEjs
Извините за супер глупый вопрос, я забыл как это делается.
let Query = "INSERT INTO `clickerbot` (user_id, score, scoreUp, passiveScore) VALUES (UserDataJSON.user_id, UserDataJSON.score, UserDataJSON.scoreUp, UserDataJSON.passiveScore)";
      const response = fetch('http://SomeLink.ru/index.php?Query', {
        method: "GET"
      })

Объект должен быть вместо UserDataJSON.user_id. Объект, кстати, так и называется. А вместо Query также переменную Query. Способ с {{UserDataJSON.user_id}} не работает.
Вот полный код:
export default {
  components: {
    Alert, UserDataJSON,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      score: 0,
      scoreUp: 1,
      passiveScore: 10,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    mainBtn: function () {
      this.score+= this.scoreUp
      let Query = "INSERT INTO `clickerbot` (user_id, score, scoreUp, passiveScore) VALUES (UserDataJSON.user_id, UserDataJSON.score, UserDataJSON.scoreUp, UserDataJSON.passiveScore)";
      const response = fetch('http://SomeLink.ru/index.php?Query', {
        method: "GET"
      })
    }
  },
  computed: {
    scoreUpdate: function () {
      setInterval((id: 2) => {
        this.score += this.passiveScore
        clearInterval(id)
      }, 2000)
    }
  }
}


в python  например используется f строка и переменная заключается в скобки. А здесь, насколько я помню, двойные фигурные скобки использовались, типа: {{UserDataJSON.user_id}}

sql запрос с фронта отправлять? может не надо ?)

В JS объедение строк идет через + 'строка' + переменная или через шаблонные строки, заключенные в кавычки Выглядит это так`строка${переменная}``

всё выражение берёте в обратные кавычки,а внутри ${UserDataJSON.user_id} в таком виде пишете. А обратные кавычки внутри запроса экранируете.
